# ¿Cómo cambiar nombre a un botón de un datagrid al dar clic?

Tags: c#

Buenas comunidad, consulta!

Estoy tratando de cambiar el texto de un botón en un datagridview, es decir quiero que en lugar de "Editar" salga "Guardar".

Este es el código que llevo:

```
dgvDocumentos[3, indexDocumento].Value = "Guardar";
```

Comment: Pero que error obtienes al hacer eso?

Comment: No lo cambia y no encuentro la propiedad "Text".

Answer (score 1):

Debes establecer la propiedad `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` a `false` para poder modificar el texto de los botones individualmente:

```
((DataGridViewButtonColumn)dgvDocumentos.Columns[3]).UseColumnTextForButtonValue=false;
```